# How to get state from parent component using props

Tags: react-native

I new in react native and i really don't understand how to use props.I have 2 components are parent and child. So how can i get state in parent ?

I tried read many answer in here and read alot of document but with me props is very hard .

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  StackActions,
  NavigationActions,
} from 'react-navigation';

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'Hello',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Parent Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {this.props.navigation('Child')}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Child Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {console.log(this.props)}}/>     <--- show data of parent 
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Parent: {
      screen: Parent,
    },
    Child: {
      screen: Child,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Parent',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

I expect when i console log form data like this

```
>{parent: Parent}
  >parent: Parent
  >context: {}
  >props: {screenProps: undefined, navigation: {…}}
  >state: {  name: 'Hello'}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass those data from parent

```
onPress={() => {this.props.navigation('Child',{parentData:'Pass Data From Here'})}}
```

And to get those data in child

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = navigation.getParam('parentData', 'Default Value');
```

Comment: that's exactly what i want broo . thank you so much for saving my life <3

Comment: Glad to help you :)